# Is there a prob not to free the stream?

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

i have a wcf rest method what return stream,but i'm not sure stream how to free?that will be some problem? below is the demo:

```
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetImage")]  
  public Stream GetImage()  
  {  
       FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\1.jpg");  
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";  
       return fs; 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, WCF automatically disposes of the stream for you when it is done using it. for more information about the behaviour look the [AutoDisposeParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.autodisposeparameters.aspx) parameter on the [OperationBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Remember to mark answers as answered if you want folks to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use using statment that automatically frees the object.

```
using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\1.jpg"))
{
}
```

Comment: if i use using,then i can't return the stream

Comment: -1: won't work: stream will be disposed before WCF can use it to send the data.